# Make a MySQL query reusable with double ?? for tables and ? for selectors with NodeJS and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

**Hi. I am looking to create a reusable query with MySQL and NodeJS**

The first step I took after the DB connection was to create a data access object and interact with the DB while using promises. To stay relative secure, I am using placeholders:

- " ? " for rows and values and double " ?? " for tables.

I want to create functions to be reused. So if I am creating one function for insert, I need to use same function to insert records in different tables while using parameters.

1. The Data access layer looks like this: Here I am using parameters that will go to each function and replace the placeholders from the sql statements.

   ```
          /* 
              Insert user accepts three parameters. Statement from mysql, table marked with ?? in the statement and the 
              payload object that have to match the database columns 
          */
          insertRecord: (sqlStatement, table, payload) => {
              return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                  db.query(sqlStatement, [table, payload], (error, response) => {
                  if (error) return reject(error);
                  return resolve(response);
              });
            });
          },

      /* 
          This function accepts four parametters. The first parameter is the statement. Second parameter is the table selector 
          marked with ?? in the statement.
          The selector is the row, and the value specified
      */
      selectSimpleStatement: (sqlStatement, table, row, value) => {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              db.query(sqlStatement, [table, row, value], (error, response) => {
              if (error) return reject(error);
              else return resolve(response);
          });
        });
      }
   }
   ```
2. The second implementation was to create all the MySQL queries separately because I wanted to keep it Clean

   module.exports = {
   insertStatement:            'INSERT INTO ?? SET ?',
   sqlSimpleSelect:            'SELECT * FROM ?? WHERE ? = ?'
   }
3. Using the first sql statement was easy. I worked to insert in all the tables with the same function. But the select is a pain. With postman I am getting empty arrays even if the values are correct...

````
const { sqlSimpleSelect } = require('../../database/statements.js');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');



exports.add = async (req, res, next) => {
    const {username, password} = req.body;

try {
    // Select from users where username = username variable
    const user = await selectSimpleStatement(sqlSimpleSelect, 'users', 'username', username);
    res.send(user);
} 
catch (error) {
    res.send(error)
    }
}```


I am getting empty array. Can please help me? 
Thanks, Daniel
````

Comment: *`sqlSimpleSelect: 'SELECT * FROM ?? WHERE ? = ?' }`* - this is incorrect. Column name or another object name must be encoded with double question mark, like it is done for table name, rather than a value which should be encoded with single quotation mark: `sqlSimpleSelect: 'SELECT * FROM ?? WHERE ?? = ?' }`.